# Is there a way to display rows and columns within an accordion?

Tags: html, css, panel, css-multicolumn-layout, bootstrap-accordion

Problem: I have a list of records that can sometimes be long. I'd like to display the list in 4 columns within an accordion.

Note: For the sake of this example, I'm only trying to display 2 columns.

1) The following accordion (with the appropriate style settings) works but it's messy as it displays the rows horizontally.

```
<button class="accordion">NUMBER OF RIDES PER JOCKEY</button>

<div class="panel">

    <p><p class="break-word" align="justify"><p style="line-height:18px;"><font face="Lato"><font size="1.5"><font color="#000000"><b>ADAM HYERONIMUS</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>BRENTON AVDULLA</b> HAS <b>6</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>GLYN SCHOFIELD</b> HAS <b>1</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>JASON COLLETT</b> HAS <b>4</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>KERRIN MCEVOY</b> HAS <b>7</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>NOT DECLARED</b> HAS <b>7</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>TOMMY BERRY</b> HAS <b>9</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>ANDREW ADKINS</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>BROCK RYAN</b> HAS <b>4</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>HUGH BOWMAN</b> HAS <b>6</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>JAY FORD</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>LUKE CURRIE</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY. <b>ROBBIE DOLAN</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</font></p>

</div>
```

2) The following code (without button class="accordion") displays the rows and columns the way I'd like, however, when I add the "button class="accordion", it doesn't work. It simply displays a non-functioning button, followed by the 2 columns of data.

```
<button class="accordion">NUMBER OF RIDES PER JOCKEY</button>

<div class="panel">

   <div class="row">

      <!-- Column 1 -->
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
     <p style="line-height:18px;"><font face="Lato"><font size="1.5"><font color="#000000">
         <p><b>ADAM HYERONIMUS</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>BRENTON AVDULLA</b> HAS <b>6</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>GLYN SCHOFIELD</b> HAS <b>1</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>JASON COLLETT</b> HAS <b>4</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>KERRIN MCEVOY</b> HAS <b>7</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>NOT DECLARED</b> HAS <b>7</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>TOMMY BERRY</b> HAS <b>9</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
      </div>

      <!-- Column 2 -->
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
     <p style="line-height:18px;"><font face="Lato"><font size="1.5"><font color="#000000">
         <p><b>ANDREW ADKINS</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>BROCK RYAN</b> HAS <b>4</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>HUGH BOWMAN</b> HAS <b>6</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>JAY FORD</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>LUKE CURRIE</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>ROBBIE DOLAN</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
      </div>

</div>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your second example. You are trying to nest a bunch of p tags inside another p tag. This doesn't work in html; use a div tag instead. Also, you are not closing those parent p tags. 
Assuming you are using html 5, the font tag is deprecated. Use css for your font instead. 
Start with this for some improved markup and then just apply the font css. Also, not sure what the javascript driving the open/close of the accordion looks like so I can't verify that it will work.

```
<button class="accordion">NUMBER OF RIDES PER JOCKEY</button>

<div class="panel">

   <div class="row">

      <!-- Column 1 -->
      <div  class="column" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">

         <p><b>ADAM HYERONIMUS</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>BRENTON AVDULLA</b> HAS <b>6</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>GLYN SCHOFIELD</b> HAS <b>1</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>JASON COLLETT</b> HAS <b>4</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>KERRIN MCEVOY</b> HAS <b>7</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>NOT DECLARED</b> HAS <b>7</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>TOMMY BERRY</b> HAS <b>9</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
      </div>

      <!-- Column 2 -->
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">

         <p><b>ANDREW ADKINS</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>BROCK RYAN</b> HAS <b>4</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>HUGH BOWMAN</b> HAS <b>6</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>JAY FORD</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>LUKE CURRIE</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
         <p><b>ROBBIE DOLAN</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.column {
  font-family:'Lato';
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sthurston I had some time to work on it & got it to work. I probably should have added more info to the original post along with the proper css.

Please see below if you (or anyone else is) interested in the solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .accordion {
        background-color: #388070;
        color: #ffffff;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 12px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 2px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: f0f0f0;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        transition: 0.4s;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .active, .accordion:hover {
        background-color: #388070; 
    }

    .accordion:after {
        content: '\002B'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #f5f5f5;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .active:after {
        content: "\2212"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
    }

    .panel {
        padding: 0 12px;
        display: none;
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-color: #000000;
        font-family:'Lato';
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height:18px
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        overflow: hidden;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        text-align: justify;
    }

    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-color: #000000;
        font-family:'Lato';
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height:18px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button class="accordion">TODAY'S SCRATCHINGS (AT A GLANCE)</button>

    <div class="panel">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="column">
                <p><b>&nbsp&nbspADAM HYERONIMUS</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>&nbsp&nbspBRENTON AVDULLA</b> HAS <b>6</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>&nbsp&nbspGLYN SCHOFIELD</b> HAS <b>1</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>&nbsp&nbspJASON COLLETT</b> HAS <b>4</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>&nbsp&nbspKERRIN MCEVOY</b> HAS <b>7</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>&nbsp&nbspNOT DECLARED</b> HAS <b>7</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>&nbsp&nbspTOMMY BERRY</b> HAS <b>9</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <p><b>ANDREW ADKINS</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>BROCK RYAN</b> HAS <b>4</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>HUGH BOWMAN</b> HAS <b>6</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>JAY FORD</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>LUKE CURRIE</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>ROBBIE DOLAN</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="column"> 
                <p><b>BLAIKE MCDOUGALL</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>CHRIS WILLIAMS</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>JAKE HULL</b> HAS <b>1</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>JOSH PARR</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>MIKAYLA WEIR (APPRENTICE)</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>SAM CLIPPERTON</b> HAS <b>2</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <p><b>BRAD STEWART</b> HAS <b>1</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>GLEN BOSS</b> HAS <b>6</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>JAMES MCDONALD</b> HAS <b>7</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>KATHY O'HARA</b> HAS <b>5</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>NASH RAWILLER</b> HAS <b>9</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
                <p><b>TIM CLARK</b> HAS <b>6</b> RIDE(S) TODAY.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                panel.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                panel.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```